# how to create a gradient border for a div box?

Tags: css

I used the following code but I can't create the gradient of this box. I want to create a gradient border of a div, to show only around the top border and a little on the left and right

```css
.HH {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #000;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #000;
  /* Safari, Chrome */
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #000;
  /* CSS3 */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="HH">
  HI
</div>
```

Comment: best is to look at descriptions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image give it a try and tell us then where you fail ;)

Comment: check this https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/

Comment: You can also try this https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvwZMxj or this https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOYyrMj

Comment: Corrected (hopefully) some grammatical errors and repetitions, to make the question clearer.